# I am not able to save the quantity of my ordered items in the local storage with react and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, shopping-cart

I'm a beginner javascript developer. I am trying to create a component for adding a product to the shopping cart with React, using local storage. I manage to register the id of my product by clicking on the button, but I cannot increment a quantity on a product ordered more than once.
This is my composant :

```
import React from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

function AddToBasket() {
const id = useParams().id;

let cartProduct = [];
let cartQty = [];

  function handleClick(AddToBasket,e) {

    if (localStorage.getItem('cartProduct') != null) {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('cartProduct'));
        var localProduct = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartProduct'));
        var localQty = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartQty'));



        if (localProduct.indexOf(id)!== -1) { 
            var indexId = 0;
            indexId = localProduct.indexOf(id); 
            console.log(indexId);
            localProduct.forEach((indexId) => {
            localProduct.push(id);
            localQty++})
            localStorage.setItem('cartProduct', JSON.stringify(localProduct));
            localStorage.setItem('cartQty', JSON.stringify(localQty));
        }

        else {
            localProduct.push(id);
            localQty.push(1);
            console.log(cartProduct);
            localStorage.setItem('cartProduct', JSON.stringify(localProduct));
            localStorage.setItem('cartQty', JSON.stringify(localQty));
        }

    }

    else {
        cartProduct.push(id);
        cartQty.push(1);
        console.log(cartProduct);
        localStorage.setItem('cartProduct', JSON.stringify(cartProduct));
        localStorage.setItem('cartQty', JSON.stringify(cartQty));
    }

}

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Ajout au panier</button>
        )

}

export default AddToBasket;
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler reaches the else part after finding a particular ID, it always pushes 1 to the quantity. I don't see any increment done here. So the `localQty` is repeatedly being assigned with the value 1. Try to increment, the value. You are using plain JavaScript, there's no use of React here. If you're don't have a complete understanding of JS, please don't proceed with ReactJS as you might end up hating the library. Hope it helps!..